# Does the += operator just not exist in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, operators

I'm trying to incriment the value in a cell, but despite documentation saying Visual Basic allows the += operator, it's just giving me "Compile error: Expected: expression".

```
Range("CellName").Value += 1
```

Is what's breaking, but if I do

```
Range("CellName") = Range("CellName") + 1
```

It works fine

Comment: `VBA` is quite different from `VB.net` - `VBA` isn't so strict with type  but then again `VB.net` isn't as strict as `c#`. I like them all - `VBA` seems limited but if you are playing with Excel then `VBA` is part of the application so can be really powerful.

Answer (score 17):

No, it doesn't exist in VBA.

VB.NET might take `+=` (though I'm not even sure about that).

You'll have to use

```
Range("CellName").Value = Range("CellName").Value+1
```

A good reference can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/4410/increment-and-decrement-operator-in-vb-net.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

An "official" list of VBA-operators can be found in VBA help here:

Help --> Microsoft Visual Basic Help --> Visual Basic for Applications Language Reference --> Visual Basic Language Reference --> Operators --> Arithmetic Operators ([online here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264381%28v=office.15%29.aspx) )

Maybe controversially, but the next advice would have saved me lots of time and headaches:

I'd say it's better to forget *everything* about VB and focus at VBA, as the two are different languages. People don't mention "Oh, OCaml, APL, PHP or Fortran have increment operators", as it's off-topic if the scope is VBA. In the same way, what VB has or has not is off-topic, and usually it only adds to the confusion because it's resemblance. Better use the MS-Office provided "local" Visual Basic for Applications Language Reference as provided by the help system, or online:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: According to that official list, VBA doesn't have a += operator.

Don't forget to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's really annoying. I made the following functions to make my life a bit easier:

```
' ++
Function pp(ByRef x, Optional y = 1)
    x = x + y
    pp = x
End Function

' --
Function mm(ByRef x, Optional y = 1)
    x = x - y
    mm = x
End Function
```

Doesn't really help your situation as you'd still have to type the same amount:

```
Range("CellName") = pp(Range("CellName"))
```

but for simple loop increments it helps :

```
do while cells(x,1) <> ""
    pp x
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

No it does not have it for numbers, e.g. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/215yacb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx / http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx